BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic returning 201 error code
i have a project in which i need to connect to a BLE server running on a esp32, but when i try to write to a characteristic , the esp does not receive it and writeCharacteristic return 201.
This is how I created the characteristic on the esp32
caracteristicRecive=service->createCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_2 , BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                  BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE|
                  BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
                  BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE);
  BLE2902 * desc= new BLE2902();
  desc->setNotifications(true);
  caracteristicRecive->addDescriptor(desc); 
  caracteristicRecive->setCallbacks(new MyCharacteristicCallback());

and in Android Studio
this.characteristicSend = service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("f61ad6ec-247b-44e9-98e1-f2a61b9836ea"));
        this.characteristicRecive = service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("df847cb0-69aa-43e1-8aa9-1fad496c60b5"));
        btGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristicRecive, true);
        BluetoothGattDescriptor desc = characteristicRecive.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        btGatt.writeDescriptor(desc, BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        if(!aes.createSessionKey()) disconnect();    
        int res=btGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristicSend, aes.encrypt(aes.sesKey), BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
        Log.d("data",String.valueOf(res));

The first thing I am trying to send is the session key for encrypting the hanshake and data of the current session, but esp does not receive it and everything stalls
P.s the phone in case is a Xiaomi 12 running android 14
I tried adding all the permissions necessary i could find and running on other devices but still nothing

You can only have one pending GATT operation at a time. You must wait for the onDescriptorWrite callback before you can send writeCharacteristic.
